# CreateDateColumn/UpdateDateColumn save an incorrect date

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have a problem at the moment to create or updating a register. The issue is, that the time saved in the columns `CreateDateColumn/UpdateDateColumn`, saves a different hour compare with the time on my local computer. For example, if I do an update, and the time was 18:05:25, in the table database I could see 23:05:25. Could any person help me with some settings that probably I am missing?

Time when I update the register

[image]

Time save at the columns the automatic way on the database

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between your timezone and UTC? I believe TypeORM sets those columns to be UTC based instead of based on local timezone

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Eight hours is the difference

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps can be set by the database itself, if you have default value `now()` in this columns. Check database timezone setting. In Postgres it's `SHOW time zone;`